# gem install rails failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to install rails however getting the following error:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rack-test)
```

Machine: Ubuntu Precise 32x running in Vagrant

I tried this with sudo and infact get a different error:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler)
```

Comment: Does `curl https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rack-test` work in the console?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access this URL, however it returns a 302 Found.

Comment: That's 99% a network issue.

Comment: I am able to get to apt-get repositories, I am able to curl google.com, it appears I am fully connected to the network.

Comment: Are you able to access secure sites i.e. `https`?

Comment: try from console: `telnet api.rubygems.org 443` and show the output